# visual jquery ui designer bug?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have started a visual jquery ui designer:

http://www.fivetechsoft.net/cgi-bin/fiveform

but got this problem: once a new control is added, the draggable and resizable features of the previous ones, become unavailable. Is this a known jquery ui bug ? Do you see some bug in the code I use in javascript functions AddSay() and AddButton() (inside fiveweb.js) ? thanks

Antonio

Comment: fiveform is built using Harbour and FiveWeb: http://code.google.com/p/fiveweb/

Answer (score 0):

Solved! :-)

The solution was not to modify the innerHTML property directly, instead use the DOM object! (javascript functions AddSay() and AddButton() in fiveweb.js)